# How to create proper time formate with current time line show in JKCalendar event list using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to integrate third party custom calendar into my application. Here, I need to change proper time `formate 24 hours` like `(12 AM or PM)` and need to show `current time` red line like a Apple Calendar. I tried Calendar kit but there is some unmatchable functionality for my scenario. So, I need to customize `JKCalendar`, How to achieve this?

**Sample Code**

https://github.com/JoeCiou/JKCalendar

**Date Code**

```
extension TableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 48
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0 && indexPath.row != 47{
            let hour = indexPath.row / 2
            cell.timeLabel.text = (hour < 10 ? "0": "") + String(hour) + ":00"
        }else{
            cell.timeLabel.text = ""
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

**Sample Image**

[image]

Comment: “I need to change proper time”, could you explain this in more detail? Do you want a 12h or 24h format, is this to replace what you have now for your timeLabel or...?

Comment: I need to show 24h format in left side label with AM or PM. Also, I don't know how to show the redline regarding current time. @Joakim Danielson

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is there anything idea?

Comment: You don't show 24h time with AM/PM, its either 24h time or 12h time with AM/PM. 14:34 or 02:34 PM